# Update Service Fabric WebSite

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, .net-core

I am developing a Service Fabric "Asp.net Core" application. When ever I update the HTML I have to deploy (build --> Deploy) the entire Fabric Application to see the changes. Isn't there another way that just will allow me to refresh the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very well written article on dzone that describes some slight project modifications you can make to be able to run your ASP.NET CORE Applications on Service Fabric, or outside from the application directory via command line.  I found the approach very useful, and it may help you.

https://dzone.com/articles/aspnet-core-with-kestrel-and-service-fabric